# AWK: best way to sum column 9, print total along with filename?

Tags: awk

So I have about 303 of these [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Lt5.png). They all have the same format but vary in length. I need to sum and print column 9 and capture the file path. Desired format is:

```
Filepath    sum of column 9
```

I can easily print the total of column 9 by using:

```
awk '{ sum += $9 } END { print sum }'
```

But I'm having trouble printing the file path (not file name) to the left of it with 2-3 spaces in between.

This is probably simple but I'm not seeing it... 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: So if your input file is `/foo/bar/myname.txt` you want the output to include `/foo/bar` but not `myname.txt`? Or do you mean something else? [edit] your question to clarify and show exactly what the problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: Do you want to display the sum for *each* file, or for *all* files? Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Use `FILENAME`

```
$ awk '{sum+=$9} END {print FILENAME" "sum}' File
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk, you can use the special BEGINFILE and ENDFILE blocks

```
$ cat f1
13319
17767
18810
19357

$ cat f2
19631
16305
2962
19733

$ gawk 'BEGINFILE {sum = 0} {sum += $1} ENDFILE {print FILENAME, sum}' f1 f2
f1 69253
f2 58631
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think I answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that nicely with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel --tag --quote awk '{t+=$9} END{print t+0}' ::: file*
```

- `--tag` will tag each line with the filename
- `--quote` handles quoting the `awk` script
- `:::` marks the start of the parameters (filenames)